# C&C on a minimal logo that represents my name ("octopod")

Tags: vector, logo, critique, branding

I am very much dying for a second opinion on a logo that brands my name. I have gone through many different logos without asking what other people think of them.

The goal here is to represent my name in a way that is text-less and minimal. For example, this here is my latest attempt: (ignore the text, the logo is the important thing here)

[image: latest logo]

This logo is also used in most of my avatars (note the one I'm using on this website right now is a shortened version of the logo above)

This are my questions to you guys:

- **Does the design look too plain / generic?** I kind of think it is, I mean it is just 9 circles. If so, what can I do to make it less so?
- **Does it represent my name well enough in the literal sense?** My name and logo can be used for any kind of work I make, so I can't put anything in the design that defines the logo as belonging to any one type of work.
- **Am I going in the right direction?** Refer to the below logos; they are what I've done in the past. Am I making any kind of improvement with this logo compared to my past logos, in regards to the previous two questions?

Also, the logo should (and feel free to question my goals for the logo):

- **I don't want to combine the logo and text.** Refer to my past logos below, where I have tried stuff like "8P", "p8d", the giant "8". I liked the idea at one point, but I don't think they represent the name as well as a good logo does. Obviously, in the below logos I did combine the logo and text, but the main thing is I want the logo to work by itself as well.
- **I want to keep it minimal.** By "minimal", I want it in a vector form, where in the end it's just a solid shape that I can fill with any color. And also "minimal" as in simple; I don't want to have to make complex shapes in the logo. Again, refer to my past logos; they're all solid shapes.
- **It should *only* represent my name.** As stated earlier, I make various things, so I don't want to define the logo as belonging to any one type of work I make.

To further emphasize that I've gone through many logos, here is an .ai I made organizing my past logos from oldest to newest:

[image]
<sub>(source: [puu.sh](https://puu.sh/d84KY/33fedc9429.png))</sub>

In addition to the main questions above, additional opinions and critique is appreciated. I really want to settle on a logo already, because this is insane.

Also, if it already wasn't clear, the logo should represent my username, which is "octopod".

Comment: Skip "p8d" - I am probably not alone to read "Peighted", in the same way you can write skate as "Sk8"...

Comment: @HenrikEkblom: actually that was one of the "experiment" logos I tried, I ended up not using it for that exact same reason

Comment: Yeah, I'm with @HenrikEkblom on "p8d" Nice idea and I can see what you was trying to achieve. What does your brand name do/represent?

Comment: octopod sounds like a underwater vehicle shaped like a octopus in a childrens story. Wait wait it is, not sure its a good idea to use this name.

Comment: eh, from personal experience very few people actually related "octopod" to the toy, and besides, i've used that name for years, while i've thought about changing it, the bottom line is that it's too much a hassle to do so; i've registered for many things under the name.

Comment: @SaturnsEye also, the logo is very much for a generic purpose; maybe it'll be used to brand code? graphic design? games? music? it really could be anything.

Comment: When I entered "octopod" in Wikipedia, it was directed to "octopus", i.e. the cephalopod mollusc of the order Octopoda. I like your idea of having a simple icon representing the name. In your designs you have been focusing on the "8", while the name is rather "having 8 legs". Maybe the 8 dots should be connected to a head in the middle of the icon, possibly with large eyes? The appearance could also be spider-like instead of squid-like. Are there other animals with eight legs?

Comment: @Aziraphale thanks for the comment. I realize how similar the name is to 'octopus' and I've considered designing a logo in relation to that, I'm blanking out thinking of a minimal way to design an octopus/squid/spider as you mention. It'd be nice to find a nice way to design one with the least amount of strokes (like how Twitter designed their bird logo), but again, I'm blanking out.

Comment: Just so you know, squids have 10-12 “feet,” rather than 8. Arachnids in general (spiders, but also scorpions, ticks, mites, harvestmen, and various other crawlies) have 8 legs (it's their defining feature) while most crustaceans (crabs, lobsters, and so on) have 10 or more and insects have 6. But ultimately *octopod* is an alternate form of *octopus* (and *octopodes* is the etymologically-correct plural of *octopus*), so if you go for an animal, it should be that one.

Comment: Layman here, the logo kind of resembles a clothing button to me, which you might not want - perhaps change the sizes of the white circles... how about randomly sized circles.  Also, have you noticed 'octopod' has *oc*   t   *op*   *od*, which could resemble 3 eights on their side (?maybe that's not helpful).

Comment: Merriam-Webster gives only one definition of "octopod" and it's "any of an order (Octopoda) of cephalopod mollusks (as an octopus or argonaut) that have eight arms bearing sessile suckers". If there was/is a toy with that name, I must have been out of the target market when it was around - never heard of it. I'd only associate the word with the sea creatures.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't familiar with the name Octopod before seeing this. If the purpose of the name is significantly detached from the toy of the same name then I think you're OK to go with it.

With the most recent design you've shown, I think having the eight dots in the circle is an elegant way of visually representing the name and worth pursuing. I feel that whilst it would seem a logical design choice to pair the circular font with the very circular logo, it lacks contrast and tension because the structure is very passive.

I think what you have here is a start point from which to explore a variety of approaches, which can be done whilst retaining the eight circles inside the shape. Some of these could be:

Use a squarer font, or very square font and investigate creating contrast in shapes.

Create a colour version as well as a black and white version, and play with shapes overlapping, such as overlapping circles of different colour in subtractive or additive manner to make the main circle.

Play with the hierarchy of logo to text.

Incorporate the symbol into the text itself.

These are just a few suggestions which could be points for exploration. You should be able to add more.

I think you should be confident in the idea, because it feels like a good one (latest version) but just needs exploring in depth now - and ideally in colour too.

Comment: Hi user2228862, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, a logo shouldn't be too complicated, should be easy to remember, and shouldn't have a buckload of text; your logos seem to have neither of those, and I must say I love all of them. If you feel like it, add colour too? If you're considering to add colour, I would suggest to stick to one - too many will make your logo stand out, but will make it a little bit more complicated and will make it look less professional - or so I feel.

I love your most recent design, the nine circles (it makes me think of a button, to be honest) - but I also love the octagon with the eight circles - I feel that it gives a little bit more meaning to the name "octo". I think it represents your name "Octopod" well, leaving room for interpretation of what you do. It doesn't narrow it down to one item or group of items.

Hope this helped!

Comment: i'd have to say though -- having 8 sides *and* 8 dots is probably putting a lot of emphasis on the "octo" of my name. thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Yes, that's true - I didn't consider that. Either way, I think the octagon and the circle with the 8 dots a fantastic idea - it looks clean, simple and memorable :)